# Trying to use mongoose with node-webkit target on Webpack

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-webkit, webpack

I use webpack and target it's build output for `node-webkit`. I want to require the `mongoose` module inside my project to connect to mongodb, but it always states some errors when I try to pack the project:

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/x64/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 6:10-37

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/ia32/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 8:10-38

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 10:10-42 15:9-41

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/kerberos.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/kerberos.js 1:15-51

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_credentials.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_credentials.js 1:32-74

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_context.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_context.js 1:28-70

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer.js 1:27-69

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer_descriptor.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer_descriptor.js 1:37-79
```

It seems like webpack is unable to load `.node` files, so I installed the `node-loader` and added to my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './ui/index.jsx',
    target: 'node-webkit',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build-ui',
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.target.mk$/,
                loader: "raw-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.node$/,
                loader: "node-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

But it still throws that errors and warnings. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you run it with `--display-error-details` and see if it provides details as to why it cannot resolve it?

Comment: As mention in issue with karma-webpack try to set resolve.root to your absolute path. Reference: https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack/issues/33

Comment: I've set the `resole.root` param to `//Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes`. In this directory all my source and installed `node_modules` are placed. But still no luck. Same errors.

So it really seems like either webpack is unable to find the module (which would be strange since it's there) or unable to load, which is also strange, since I installed the node-loader. Any other guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After displaying error details the error was pretty clear.

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/x64/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/x64/bson.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 6:10-37

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/ia32/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/win32/ia32/bson.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 8:10-38

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 10:10-42 15:9-41

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/kerberos.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/kerberos.js 1:15-51

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_credentials.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist (directory default file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_credentials.js 1:32-74

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_context.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist (directory default file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_context.js 1:28-70

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist (directory default file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer.js 1:27-69

ERROR in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer_descriptor.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../build/Release/kerberos in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers
resolve file
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos doesn't exist (directory default file)
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.js]
[/Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.jsx]
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers/security_buffer_descriptor.js 1:37-79
```

So I just forgot to add `.node` to the `resolve.extensions` array.

Comment: Yes it was helpful, but didn't provide the answer.